# Custom errors on MVC 4 Web API before controller action is invoked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Based on [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) article I've implemented my own `ExceptionFilterAttribute` and registered the filter in `GlobalConfiguration` for custom exception handling in MVC 4 Web API.

However the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` only gets invoked for exceptions thrown in a controller action, **after** the request is resolved by the Framework.

I'd like to also implement custom error handling for exceptions thrown before a controller action is called. For example, an exception that is thrown in a `DelegatingHandler` currently returns me the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.</title>
        ...
```

***What do I need to do to return my own custom error for this scenario?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DelegatingHandler exceptions are generated from filters that you've written, then you can add another filter to "trap" some of these exceptions as [shown in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474076/exception-handling-beyond-exception-filters?answertab=votes#tab-top).

As you've found out and is documented in that SO answer, you are very limited in which exceptions you'll actually "trap" from the Web API pipeline. The only option I see to try to do what you're describing is to write a custom `HttpMessageHandler` as [demonstrated in this good article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/http-message-handler-in-Asp-Net-web-api/).