# Webapi HttpError missing exception information

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, http-error

I am getting a webapi HttpError from my application, which is expected, but its missing the exceptionMessage, exceptionType and stacktrace properties

Here is the odd part - If I run my app locally (windows 8, IIS) I see the the missing properties in the response:

{
message: "An error has occurred."
exceptionMessage: "unable to continue."
exceptionType: "System.ApplicationException"
stackTrace: null
}

Now when I build the app and deploy it to our test server (windows server 2008 r2), here is the response:

{
message: "An error has occurred."
}

I have compared IIS locally and on the test server, but I am not seeing any differences.  I also made sure that we were running the same version of .net.

Any ideas?

Comment: I created an HttpError() and returned it via Request.CreateErrorResponse and I was able to see the the exceptionMessage through.  It seems like an IIS setting that is filtering those HttpError properties

Comment: Are you deploying application on test server in release or debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

I had add this line to my webapiconfig:

config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

[HTTPError Exception Message not displaying when webapi is run on Server vs being run locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278072/httperror-exception-message-not-displaying-when-webapi-is-run-on-server-vs-being)

Comment: I had a look at this but I would recommend against this solution as it also sends a full stack trace in the error detail. That is the sort of thing you don't really want in a production system.